# Wake-On-Lan - Behind Two Routers

Tags: router, lan, wake-on-lan, magic-packet

So here is my current network setup:
There is a central 'Cisco' router for the apartment.  I connect wirelessly using an old router of mine (WRT54Gv2) with DD-WRT installed as a client to the central wireless network.

My router, using DD-WRT, supports dynamic dns and the like (and I'm open to that solution).

So, I would like to send a magic packet to my client router (or to the central router, if that isn't messy) to wake up my computer remotely, so that I can access it when I'm not at home.

I have an ASROCK|P67 EXTREME4 motherboard with support for Wake-On-Lan.  The computer would automatically boot into an Ubuntu 11.10 that I would tunnel into using ssh or for graphical usage something like VNC.

Comment: I have been trying to figure this out literally for a few years, but have not been able to figure it out with my DD-WRT and Linksys routers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WOL packets need to be issued from the network the machine to be woken is on.  They are sent to a MAC address and so cannot be routed across networks - they cannot be forwarded by routers from one network to another.  Is the dd-wrt router on the same network as the PC?

If so, you could issue the wol packet from the [dd-wrt router](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/WOL)

Comment: Did something similar to this with an ASA-5505. Basically, you manually add the mac/ip address pair to the router arp table so the powered down system is findable by ip and then send the magic packet to the actual assigned ip address, not the broadcast address. I can light the system over VPN from 3000 miles away.

Comment: Oh really?  That is interesting!   So you have the arp entry statically defined.  And you issue the wol packet to 10.1.1.1 from wherever, it gets routed all the way to the ASA, then the ASA looks at its arp table and sends the WOL to the mac it has for 10.1.1.1?  Clever.  You should add this as an answer, as it wasn't exactly what I was suggesting and is a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

Wake-On-Lan packets cannot be routed (they work on local network only, routers won't pass them through.

However, according to [Wikipedia article on Wake-on-LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Subnet_directed_broadcasts), there is such thing as "Subnet Directed Broadcasts", which, if supported by all routers along the path and by the target computer, could be used to send WOL packet across the router boundary. I highly doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

How to make WOL work through multiple routers.
I am using a Netgear R7000 with firmware V1.0.9.64_10.2.64 as my internal router.

Create port forwarding xxxx (the port you pick for your outside WOL port of the computer you wish to wake) UDP to the WAN address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and port xxxx of the next interior router. Repeat the same port forwarding until you reach the router where your WOL PC is connected to.  On this router the external port xxxx will match the port number to above.  Your internal port will be 255 and your internal IP address will be your WOL computer.

Use WOL software on your phone or computer with the MAC Address of your WOL computer. You will need to have your outermost router's WAN address or use a DDNS service to route 
 to your router.

Example:  My Outside Router has an IP address of 192.168.1.1.  External Port 2559 is    forwarded to my inner router with a Wan Address of 192.168.2.1 with Internal Port of 2559. On this router External Port 2559 is forwarded to Internal Port 255, with
an Internal IP of 192.168.2.21. MY WOL computer has a static address of 192.168.2.21.

For simplicity, I suggest using the same port numbers for External and Internal Ports until you reach the router with your WOL computer which will have an Internal Port of 255.

Make sure your device manager settings for your network card is set to accept Magic packets only in the Power Settings tab.