# WoL magic packet to PC behind a DS-Lite router on IPv6

Tags: router, ipv6, wake-on-lan

This is my first time posting here, so bear with me. I have an internet connection in Germany and the router is implementing a [Dual-Stack Lite](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/concept/ipv6-dual-stack-lite-overview.html) technology to have both IPv4 and IPv6 capabilities.

The matter at hand is that I want to wake my PC from work through the internet. This was done simply before (IPv4 only) by configuring the router to packet forward on a certain port to the required machine behind it. Since my internet changed to DS-Lite, I have tried everything I know to reach my PC from outside with no success.

There are some things I've encountered while trying to solve this issue that I don't really understand... like when I ask whatismyipaddress, it provides me with a public IPv4 address (my router connection to the internet through IPv4) and a global uni-cast IPv6 address (My PC IPv6). I can't ping either of them through the internet, but I can ping my router's IPv6 address which I can find in the router web page info.

With all the tests I've done, I've had Wireshark running on my PC trying to detect the WoL magic packet to eliminate BIOS or hardware problems (the packet simply is not reaching its destination) and I don't know if there is a way to trace it and see where it is stopping!

I will attach a screenshot of my router config and my PC `ipconfig`.

Any help would really be appreciated since this matter is eating me alive and it has transcended from being able to start my PC to really understanding what is happening and why it is not working. Thanks for considering my problem.

---

*IpConfig Output*

[image: IpConfig Output]

---

*Router Rules Config*

[image: Router Rules Config]

---

*Router Info*
[image: Router Info]

Comment: Please post the textual data (```ipconfig``` output and WAN IP settings) as text rather than an image.

Comment: i am sorry for posting it as an image, i will do it next time as text. just to be clear you don't have an answer for me only this comment?

Comment: I don’t have an answer.  Since nobody else has contributed anything, after 19 hours, I’ll add some slightly more substantive comments. It seems to me that you’re skimming over some important details.  Are you saying that this was working, and it stopped working when something changed?  (Or are you saying that you’re just now trying this for the first time?)  I’m a little surprised that it ever worked.  WoL can be tricky; WoL through a router doubly so, and maybe even worse if the router is doing NAT. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … If it was working, please describe in as much detail as you can *what changed.*  Is it just a new router? or a new ISP? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Upon rereading your question, I picked up on a detail that I missed yesterday: Are you saying that now, *even when your (home?) computer is up and running,* you cannot communicate to it *in any way* from the outside?  If that’s the case, then it’s no surprise that you can’t wake it up when it’s asleep, and you should [edit] your question to focus on the total lack of connectivity.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … Is it possible that your new ISP (if you have a new ISP) is blocking incoming connection attempts to your home? Are you saying that you can ping your home router *from the outside* (with IPv6)? Can you connect to your home router from the outside with TCP (i.e., access its web interface)? Can you connect to your work network from your home computer? And it might help if you described *exactly* how you are trying to send the WoL packet.

Comment: Well, John Nash seems to have given up on us — he hasn’t logged in for two weeks.   In case anybody cares, [this answer](https://superuser.com/q/1416311/150988#1416313) says “You can not send Wake-On-Lan over WAN.”  It doesn’t offer any references, but it does have two up votes, so somebody seems to believe that it’s true.

Comment: But see also [Wake-On-Lan – Behind Two Routers](https://superuser.com/q/343431/150988).